# moving all files from sub-subfolders to the main subfolder inside the parent directory

Tags: windows-10, files-folders

Say I have a file system like:

```
folder 1
- subfolder
    -sub-subfolder 1
              -file 1
              -file 2
              -file 3
    -sub-subfolder 2
              -file 4
              -file 5
              -file 6

folder 2
- subfolder
    -sub-subfolder 1
              -file 1
              -file 2
              -file 3
    -sub-subfolder 2
              -file 4
              -file 5
              -file 6
```

and I want to stream-line it to

```
folder 1
- subfolder
   -file 1
   -file 2
   -file 3
   -file 4
   -file 5
   -file 6


folder 2
- subfolder
   -file 1
   -file 2
   -file 3
   -file 4
   -file 5
   -file 6
```

except there are way more folders so the usual *.* trick would take hours. Any script or trick would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does you have only one excess subfolder level? Does `folder N` have no files in them now? Does `sub-subfolder N` posessed in the same `subfolder` have no filename duplicates?

Comment: In batchfile. Use `forfiles` to iterate over filesystem and get full pathnames for each file. Use `for` to divide full pathname to separate folder names and filenames, build proper `move` command text and execute.